# How do I create an object with a specifically sorted key precedence or key insertion order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, object

I want to create `metadata` objects of following structure with focus on such an object's key precedence.

```
{
  glucose: {
    name: 'Glucose',
    units: 'mg/dL',
  },
  height: {
    name: 'Height',
    units: '"',
    longUnit: 'Inches',
  },
  weight: {
    name: 'Weight',
    units: 'lbs',
    longUnit: 'Pounds',
  },
  bmi: {
    name: 'BMI',
  },
  pulse: {
    name: 'Pulse',
  },
  temperature: {
    name: 'Temperature',
    units: 'F',
    longUnit: 'Fahrenheit',
  },
  respiration_rate: {
    name: 'Respiration Rate',
  },
  o2_saturation: {
    name: 'O2 Saturation',
    units: '%',
  },
}
```

Each `metadata` key is related to an item's `vital_type.name` value of the `allVitals` array. The key precedence has to follow the item-order of this array when sorted by an item's `take_on` date-value in descending order.

As for the next following `allVitals` example the `weight` value was taken later than the `glucose` value. Thus I expect the `weight` key to be inserted before the `glucose` key.

The `allVitals` array can have more than just two vital items, it could have vitals of all types and multiple of them (i.e, multiple pulse vitals, multiple weight vitals).

```
const allVitals = [{
  patient_id: 79,
  vital_type_id: 6,
  value: "9.76",
  taken_on: "2022-11-17T11:07:00.000-06:00",
  vital_type: {
    id: 6,
    name: "glucose",
    units: "mg/dL",
    created_at: "2022-11-17T13:52:00.360-06:00",
    updated_at: "2022-11-17T13:52:00.360-06:00",
  },
  notes: null,
  source: "patient_device",
  id: 1366,
  time_recorded: true,
  severity: "critical_low",
  formatted_severity: "Critical - Low",
  vital_attributes: {},
  vital_status: "valid",
}, {
  patient_id: 79,
  vital_type_id: 4,
  value: "171",
  taken_on: "2022-11-17T13:19:00.000-06:00",
  vital_type: {
    id: 4,
    name: "weight",
    units: "pounds",
    created_at: "2022-11-17T13:52:00.375-06:00",
    updated_at: "2022-11-17T13:52:00.375-06:00",
  },
  notes: null,
  source: "patient_device",
  id: 1399,
  time_recorded: true,
  severity: null,
  formatted_severity: "-",
  vital_attributes: {},
  vital_status: "valid",
}];
```

The expected new `metadata` structure then would be ...

```
{
  weight: {
    name: 'Weight',
    units: 'lbs',
    longUnit: 'Pounds',
  },
  glucose: {
    name: 'Glucose',
    units: 'mg/dL',
  },
  height: {
    name: 'Height',
    units: '"',
    longUnit: 'Inches',
  },
  bmi: {
    name: 'BMI',
  },
  pulse: {
    name: 'Pulse',
  },
  temperature: {
    name: 'Temperature',
    units: 'F',
    longUnit: 'Fahrenheit',
  },
  respiration_rate: {
    name: 'Respiration Rate',
  },
  o2_saturation: {
    name: 'O2 Saturation',
    units: '%',
  },
}
```

Comment: As an aside you can expect allVitals to always be sorted with by the latest vitals first

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: @Unmitigated added it to post

Comment: const metadata = {
  weight: {
    name: 'Weight',
    units: 'lbs',
    longUnit: 'Pounds',
  },
  glucose: {
    name: 'Glucose',
    units: 'mg/dL',
  },
  height: {
    name: 'Height',
    units: '"',
    longUnit: 'Inches',
  },
  bmi: {
    name: 'BMI',
  },
  pulse: {
    name: 'Pulse',
  },
  temperature: {
    name: 'Temperature',
    units: 'F',
    longUnit: 'Fahrenheit',
  },
  respiration_rate: {
    name: 'Respiration Rate',
  },
  o2_saturation: {
    name: 'O2 Saturation',
    units: '%',
  },
}

Comment: @TryingNewThings ... 1/2 ... One can not [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the keys of an object's entries, at least not like one can sort the items of an array. But one can [create a new object from an array of entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), where the order of key insertion resembles the one of the [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)-array.

Comment: @TryingNewThings ... 2/2 ... **Yet, the question remains** ... _"What is such a meta object good for?"_ ... After all, in case the OP wishes to iterate the object's entries in a certain order, one should go with the correctly ordered entries-array right away, since an object structure does not provide any advantages over such an array.

Comment: @TryingNewThings ... _"The `allVitals` array can have more than just two vital items, it could have vitals of all types and multiple of them (i.e, multiple pulse vitals, multiple weight vitals)."_ ... what does the expected result look like in such a case? Since the OP wants an **Object** type **just one unique key** can be taken into account. **How are two or more vitals of same type/name/key are supposed to be handled?** The OP didn't say anything on that specific matter?

Comment: Maybe take a look at the object-align npm package. It might be helpful for you (disclaimer I'm the author)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Do you really want this?

Before we look at how we might solve this, I would like to suggest that your desired format is problematic.  An object is an inherently unordered container.  Treating it as ordered is not only logically suspect, it can lead to real errors.  For most cases, when you need an ordered result, an array is cleaner.  Moreover, an array will allow you to have duplicates (multiple pulse readings, for instance.)  You can't get that with an object.  So I would suggest a much more useful and logical output format would look like this:

```js
[
  {name: 'Glucose', units: 'mg/dL',},
  {name: 'Height', units: '"', longUnit: 'Inches',},
  {name: 'Weight', units: 'lbs', longUnit: 'Pounds',},
  {name: 'BMI',},
  {name: 'Pulse',},
  {name: 'Temperature', units: 'F', longUnit: 'Fahrenheit',},
  {name: 'Respiration Rate',},
  {name: 'O2 Saturation', units: '%',},
]
```

We can touch on how to do this after discussing how to get your requested result:

### One Solution

I would build this on three utility functions, like this:

```js
const uniq = (xs) => [... new Set (xs)]

const descend = (fn) => 
  (a, b, x = fn (a), y = fn (b)) => x < y ? 1 : x > y ? -1 : 0

const sortByFixedKeys = (xs, order) => [...xs] .sort (
  (a, b, x = order .indexOf (a), y = order .indexOf (b)) => 
    x == -1 ? y == -1 ? 0 : 1 : y == -1 ? -1 : x < y ? -1 : x > y ? 1 : 0
)

const createMetadata = (vitals, types) => 
  Object .fromEntries (
    sortByFixedKeys (
      Object .keys (types), 
      uniq ([... vitals] .sort (descend (x => x .taken_on)) .map (x => x .vital_type .name))
    ) .map (key => [key, types [key]])
  )


const allVitals = [{patient_id: 79, vital_type_id: 6, value: "9.76", taken_on: "2022-11-17T11: 07: 00.000-06: 00", vital_type: {id: 6, name: "glucose", units: "mg/dL", created_at: "2022-11-17T13: 52: 00.360-06: 00", updated_at: "2022-11-17T13: 52: 00.360-06: 00"}, notes: null, source: "patient_device", id: 1366, time_recorded: true, severity: "critical_low", formatted_severity: "Critical - Low", vital_attributes: {}, vital_status: "valid"}, {patient_id: 79, vital_type_id: 4, value: "171", taken_on: "2022-11-17T13: 19: 00.000-06: 00", vital_type: {id: 4, name: "weight", units: "pounds", created_at: "2022-11-17T13: 52: 00.375-06: 00", updated_at: "2022-11-17T13: 52: 00.375-06: 00"}, notes: null, source: "patient_device", id: 1399, time_recorded: true, severity: null, formatted_severity: "-", vital_attributes: {}, vital_status: "valid"}]
const types = {glucose: {name: "Glucose", units: "mg/dL"}, height: {name: "Height", units: '"', longUnit: "Inches"}, weight: {name: "Weight", units: "lbs", longUnit: "Pounds"}, bmi: {name: "BMI"}, pulse: {name: "Pulse"}, temperature: {name: "Temperature", units: "F", longUnit: "Fahrenheit"}, respiration_rate: {name: "Respiration Rate"}, o2_saturation: {name: "O2 Saturation", units: "%"}}

console .log (createMetadata (allVitals, types))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

**`uniq`** is trivial, just returning an array with the duplicates removed.

**`descend`** turns a function that extracts an ordered value (string, number, date, `{valueOf}`) from an object into a comparator that can be passed to sort.  That comparator will sort them in a descending order.

**`sortByFixedKeys`**  is slightly more complex.  It takes an array to sort and an array of those elements with a known ordering.  It then sorts your array by the order the elements appear in the ordering.  If one is not found, it goes to the end, in the same order it was in the original array.  For example,

```js
sortByFixedKeys ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9])
//=> [8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 9, 1, 2, 4, 10, 11, 12]
```

Using these together in `createMetadata`, we pass to `sortByFixedKeys` the keys of our types, and an ordering array found by taking the unique values among the `vital_type.name` properties of our objects, once sorted descending by date.  We turn these results back into an object by mapping the resulting keys into `[key, types [key]]` pairs, and reconstructing with `createMetadata`.

Since each helper is used in only one place in the main function, we *could* inline them.  But these are genuinely useful on their own, especially the first two, so it makes sense to keep them separate.  Besides, inlining them would lead to an unholy mess!

### Alternative

To create the format I suggested, it's only a minor tweak, a simplification in fact:

```js
const createMetadata = (vitals, types) => 
  sortByFixedKeys (
    Object .keys (types), 
    uniq ([... vitals] .sort (descend (x => x .taken_on)) .map (x => x .vital_type .name))
  ) .map (x => types [x])
```

This does much the same process, but instead of mapping the results to create entry objects and then calling `Object .fromEntries`, we simply map them to the associated types.  Now we can have duplicated entries in this list, if the patient has multiple  pulse readings.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it with the help of @This Guy so I gave him an upvote

```js
const allVitals = [
  {patient_id:79,vital_type_id:4,value:"171",taken_on:"2022-11-17T13:19:00.000-06:00",vital_type:{id:4,name:"weight",units:"pounds",created_at:"2022-11-17T13:52:00.375-06:00",updated_at:"2022-11-17T13:52:00.375-06:00"},notes:null,source:"patient_device",id:1399,time_recorded:!0,severity:null,formatted_severity:"-",vital_attributes:{},vital_status:"valid"},
  {patient_id:79,vital_type_id:6,value:"9.76",taken_on:"2022-11-17T11:07:00.000-06:00",vital_type:{id:6,name:"glucose",units:"mg/dL",created_at:"2022-11-17T13:52:00.360-06:00",updated_at:"2022-11-17T13:52:00.360-06:00"},notes:null,source:"patient_device",id:1366,time_recorded:!0,severity:"critical_low",formatted_severity:"Critical - Low",vital_attributes:{},vital_status:"valid"},
];
const metadata = {
  glucose: { name: 'Glucose', units: 'mg/dL' },
  height: { name: 'Height', units: '"', longUnit: 'Inches' },
  weight: { name: 'Weight', units: 'lbs', longUnit: 'Pounds' },
  bmi: { name: 'BMI' },
  pulse: { name: 'Pulse' },
  temperature: { name: 'Temperature', units: 'F', longUnit: 'Fahrenheit' },
  respiration_rate: { name: 'Respiration Rate' },
  o2_saturation: { name: 'O2 Saturation', units: '%' },
};

const orderedVitalsArray = allVitals
  .sort((v1, v2) => moment(v2.taken_on).diff(moment(v1.taken_on)))
  .map(e => e?.vital_type?.name);

const orderedMetadata = orderedVitalsArray.reduce((current, item) => {
  current[item] = metadata[item];
  return current;
}, {});

console.log({
  orderedVitalsArray,
  orderedMetadata,
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help! This looks well done and includes some nice shortcuts and safety mechanisms.

Comment: Note that bringing in `moment` if you're not already using it, just to sort dates supplied in ISO format, seems like overkill.

Comment: I'm curious whether the `orderedMetadata` output is correct or what was requested in the post.  Other answers went through more work trying to get the output you said you wanted.  What's your goal?  And if this is the target, please edit the question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

From my above comments ...

> *"@TryingNewThings ... 1/2 ... One can not [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the keys of an object's entries, at least not like one can sort the items of an array. But one can [create a new object from an array of entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), where the order of key insertion resembles the one of the [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)-array."*

> *"@TryingNewThings ... 2/2 ... **Yet, the question remains** ... *"What is such a meta object good for?"* ... After all, in case the OP wishes to iterate the object's entries in a certain order, one should go with the correctly ordered entries-array right away, since an object structure does not provide any advantages over such an array."*

Nevertheless, what the OP wishes can be accomplished. And following steps have to be taken ...

1. **Creating an array of all correctly ordered unique metadata keys**

   - [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the `allVitals`-array by each of its item's `taken_on` date-value in a descending order ...
   - ... map each sorted item by just returning an item's `vital_type.name` ...
   - ... and [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)enate the `name`-array with all of the metadata blueprint's [`keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)-array.
   - The result of the above steps gets converted into an array of unique names/keys by passing the sorted, mapped and concatenated array into a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/Set) constructor followed by [destructuring the set into an array again](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#using_array_destructuring_on_any_iterable).

     ```
     [...new Set(
       allVitals
         .sort( compareDescendingByDateTaken )
         .map( ({ vital_type: { name }}) => name )
         .concat( Object.keys(metadataBlueprint) )
     )];
     ```
2. **Creating an array of all correctly ordered unique metadata entries**

   - [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the retrieved array of correctly ordered unique keys according to each entry of the meta data blueprint.

     ```
     [...new Set(
       allVitals
         .sort( compareDescendingByDateTaken )
         .map( ({ vital_type: { name }}) => name )
         .concat( Object.keys(metadataBlueprint) )
     )]
     .map( key => [key, metadataBlueprint[key]] );
     ```
3. **Creating another meta data object which features all entries in correct key insertion order according to the meta data blueprint and to the sorting of all vitals**

   - create the object by passing the before retrieved entries-array to [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

     ```
     Object
       .fromEntries([
         ...new Set(
           allVitals
             .sort( compareDescendingByDateTaken )
             .map( ({ vital_type: { name }}) => name )
             .concat( Object.keys(metadataBlueprint) )
         )]
         .map( key => [key, metadataBlueprint[key]] )
       );
     ```

**Implementation / Proof of concept**

```js
var allVitals = [
  {patient_id:79,vital_type_id:4,value:"171",taken_on:"2022-11-17T13:19:00.000-06:00",vital_type:{id:4,name:"weight",units:"pounds",created_at:"2022-11-17T13:52:00.375-06:00",updated_at:"2022-11-17T13:52:00.375-06:00"},notes:null,source:"patient_device",id:1399,time_recorded:!0,severity:null,formatted_severity:"-",vital_attributes:{},vital_status:"valid"},
  {patient_id:79,vital_type_id:6,value:"9.76",taken_on:"2022-11-17T11:07:00.000-06:00",vital_type:{id:6,name:"glucose",units:"mg/dL",created_at:"2022-11-17T13:52:00.360-06:00",updated_at:"2022-11-17T13:52:00.360-06:00"},notes:null,source:"patient_device",id:1366,time_recorded:!0,severity:"critical_low",formatted_severity:"Critical - Low",vital_attributes:{},vital_status:"valid"},
];

// slightly changed original key insertion order.
const metadataBlueprint = {
  weight: { name: 'Weight', units: 'lbs', longUnit: 'Pounds' },
  height: { name: 'Height', units: '"', longUnit: 'Inches' },
  bmi: { name: 'BMI' },
  temperature: { name: 'Temperature', units: 'F', longUnit: 'Fahrenheit' },
  pulse: { name: 'Pulse' },
  respiration_rate: { name: 'Respiration Rate' },
  o2_saturation: { name: 'O2 Saturation', units: '%' },
  glucose: { name: 'Glucose', units: 'mg/dL' },
};

function compareDescendingByDateTaken(a, b) {
  return (new Date(b.taken_on) - new Date(a.taken_on));
}
console.log(
  'array of all correctly ordered unique metadata keys ...', [
    ...new Set(
      allVitals
        .sort( compareDescendingByDateTaken )
        .map( ({ vital_type: { name }}) => name )
        .concat( Object.keys(metadataBlueprint) )
    )]
);
console.log(
  'array of all correctly ordered unique metadata entries ...', [
    ...new Set(
      allVitals
        .sort( compareDescendingByDateTaken )
        .map( ({ vital_type: { name }}) => name )
        .concat( Object.keys(metadataBlueprint) )
    )]
    .map( key => [key, metadataBlueprint[key]] )
);
console.log(
  'another meta data object which features all entries in correct key insertion order according to the meta data blueprint and to the sorting of all vitals ...',
  Object
    .fromEntries([
      ...new Set(
        allVitals
          .sort( compareDescendingByDateTaken )
          .map( ({ vital_type: { name }}) => name )
          .concat( Object.keys(metadataBlueprint) )
      )]
      .map( key => [key, metadataBlueprint[key]] )
    )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let solution = allVitals.reduce((initial,current)=>{
initial[current?.vital_type.name] = {
  name:current?.vital_type?.name,
  unit:current?.vital_type?.units,
  longUnit:"longUnit not available in you data object"
}
  return initial
},{})

console.log(solution)
```

for the longUnit part you will have to change it because longunit is not in you ebject data